# MySQL getting available associations through multiple 1:n tables

Tags: mysql, sql, associations

I have three tables in a standard MySQL database: Categories, Posts and Tags. Posts is associated through 1:n with both Tags and Categories. So each post has exactly one category and one tag. I was wondering if its possible to get all available tags in a category without having to associate categories and tags directly.

So for example if I had the tables:

```
post table
post ID | category ID | tag ID
----------------------------
1       | 1           | 1
2       | 1           | 2
3       | 2           | 1
4       | 3           | 3

category table
category ID | name
--------------------
1           | video
2           | image
3           | code

tag table
tag ID | name
--------------------
1      | funny
2      | info
3      | script
```

my query for category `video` should return the tags `funny, info`, a query for category `code` should only return `script`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @h.m.i.13 both aggregation and programmatically (e.g. making a LIMIT 1 query for the selected category with each tag and return the results) work, but I was thinking there has to be a faster way for this

Comment: I did a db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agnpDxaLD2vTigCWSr6Vhi/6 is the query what you are searching for?